# Android - Imports Greyed out and Giving Errors?

Tags: java, android, oracle, import, oracle-maf

I am trying to import the following and they are getting greyed out and giving an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol"

`import oracle.adf.model.datacontrols.device.DeviceManagerFactory; 
import oracle.adf.model.datacontrols.device.DeviceManager; 
import oracle.adf.model.datacontrols.device.DeviceDataControl; 
import oracle.adfmf.framework.api.AdfmfJavaUtilities`

These are valid imports but for some reason giving me errors saying they are invalid. As a result, although my code should work, it's not because its not importing these at all.

Comment: Please add a complete code example

Comment: Please state which IDE are you using, that "greys out" these imports. Maybe you just forgot to set a dependency in your project...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JDeveloper` , please follow the steps

1. Go to your project location
2. Delete "classes" folder from both Application Controller and `ViewController`
3. From your IDE clean and re-build your project.